# Pagination em relação no Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Há como fazer paginação no Laravel em `hasMany()` método para relações entre models no Laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model user:

```
public function sites() {
    return $this->hasMany(Sites::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Sites Model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
}
```

Controller:

```
User::find(122)->sites
```

Fonte: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-paginate-eloquent-hasmany-relation